# Keyring multiple login

Tags: login, google-chrome, password, keyrings

I recently started having problems with automatically logging in to Chrome.

I noticed a window for keyring logings popped up every time I started Chrome.

This is how it looks like after opening seahorse [seahorse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbjCL.png)

Right clicking one of the logins immediately makes this window pop up [timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPteE.png)

I believe this weird behavior is the root of my chrome problems. Any help?